# When I run "npm start" to run a React app , it doesn't give any errors but hangs forever instead

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start

I have already run "`npm install`" before this and all the necessary dependencies have been installed.

I've also tried uninstalling the old version of NodeJS and installing the latest version but it's still not working.

A browser window with the React app should pop up.

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1",
    "react-select": "^2.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "yarn": "^1.12.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "proxy": "http://localhost:57111/"
}
```

Comment: Did you try to access the URL manually?

Comment: Can we see your package.json scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be various reasons for the url to not automatically open up in a browser but we will know whether the server started or not by manually opening the url in the browser.

Usually the server is started in port `3000` in `localhost`. So the URL to access your site will be `http://localhost:3000` by default when you use create-react-app.

Try opening the site manually at http://localhost:3000

Comment: Thank you so much. That link redirected to my site. But do you know why it doesn't open in a browser automatically?

Comment: There can be various reasons. 1. Browser has issues with auto open, 2. terminal blocking opening up browser windows, 3. Some other security setting in the OS, etc. Can't say for sure without looking deep into everything.

Comment: I too have this problem. My system hangs terribly whenever I run `npm start`. I don't know what to do. @Dinesh

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me on Mac. A good old fashioned restart did the trick.